# Can Someone Clarify Amortized Constant Time (doubling array vectors)?

Tags: performance, algorithm, vector

I think I understand the concept. Let me explain how I understand it in terms of its application to `doubling array vectors`.

> The rate of copying items to an array remains constant. While the growth of the array is exponential, the rate at which the array needs to double in size is logarithmic. Because of this, the decreased occurrence of doubling the array size 'sort of' cancels out the resources required to double the array and copy it's elements, as this only happens `O(n Log N)` times throughout the life of the array. Thus, the `O(n^2)` for the rate of growth combined with `O(n Log N)` for the frequency at which the array grows resolves to somewhere around `O(n)`.

Is this correct? If not, which parts are wrong? I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this. I'm pretty sure that the Big Oh notation I gave is incorrect.

Thanks

Comment: I quite like the accounting method for amortized analysis. If people go to the zoo and every 2^k-th customer has to pay $2^k for entry while everyone else gets in for free, then it comes out to between $1n and $3n if a total of n customers come in. You can think of it like this: if everyone between the 2^k-th and the 2^(k+1)-th customer pays $2, then they "financed" the 2^(k+1)-th customer with constant individual overhead of $2, and now the 2^(k+1)-th customer also only has to pay $2. The idea is to see if you can distribute rare expensive cost to many operations that are cheap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you double the array when it reaches `2` elements, `4`, `8`, `16`, `32`, ..., `2^k`.

This means `O(log n)` doubling operations for an array of size `n`. It's tempting to say this makes the thing `O(n log n)`, but that's not the case.

The number of operations performed for **all of** these doubling ops is bounded above by:

```
1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2^k = (2^k - 1) (sum of geometric series)
```

Notice however that `k = number of doubling ops = O(log n)`, so we have the number of operations needed for doubling bounded above by `2^(log n) = n`

So, the whole thing remains `O(n)`: while you do a lot of operations when doubling the array, considering those "a lot of operations" in relation to the entire array size and how many times you have performed them, they are no longer "a lot", just `O(n)`.

Amortized basically means you keep the big picture in mind: sure, I might have to work a lot today, but that means I get to stay home for the rest of the week. Does that mean I will have worked a lot this week? No, I will have actually worked very little.

I think your explanation is not entirely accurate and overly complicated. There are no sort ofs, and there are no `O(n^2)` rates of growth. The math just adds up to `O(n)` as you've seen.

My suggestion in general is that you ignore the word amortized and just do the math. I've seen it cause a lot of confusion for no good reason. Sure, it might be the formal thing that's involved in such an analysis, but most of the time it will only spark confusion about what happens. Just ask yourself: "ok, how many operations will this algorithm perform?". More often than not, you won't need anything fancy to answer that question.

Answer (score 0):

Not discussing how you calculated "amortised" time, but what it's good for: You may have an algorithm that you use repeatedly to get from state 1 to state 2 to state 3 ... and so on. The cost of going from one state to another may vary wildly, and the maximum cost to go from one state to another may be very high. However, sometimes you can prove that the total cost of going through states 1 to state n is much less than n times the maximum. So the "amortised" cost is the average cost of going from state 1 to state n.

Sometimes the maximum cost may be important. For example in a music playing application, the time to output the next music sample must *always* be low, or the sound will stutter, which is not acceptable. However, in other cases, what matters is the total time to go through all the states and that is fine as long as the average is fine.

Note that amortised time is not the same as average time. An algorithm may require different time depending on the data that it is given. If some input X takes much longer than average, then it could be that you use the algorithm a million times to handle the same input X and the total time is huge.

Comment: `So the "amortised" cost is the average cost of going from state 1 to state n`, this is not true, it's the total cost. The average is smaller than the largest. How can the cost of going through them all be smaller than the largest cost of going through any two?